# How to make Z-axis (Tower series) deeper?

Tags: teechart

I have made a 3d bar chart (3-axis, tower series) and am struggling to figure out how to make the chart deeper. I have 36 rows and want the rectangles to be much thicker (than they are currently) and make the chart appear to go farther back (deeper). I also have not been able to rotate it past 45 degrees left NOR tip the front right corner down further to better show the tops of the rectangles. Is there a way to do this in TeeChart Pro 2013?? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set *Chart3DPercent* property, for example:

```
  Chart1.Chart3DPercent:=50;
```

or

```
  TChart1.Aspect.Chart3DPercent=50
```

The first one is in Delphi, the second one in Visual Basic. For a more accurate reply please let us know the TeeChart version you are using: VCL/FMX, .NET, ActiveX, Java, etc. Also, you may find information on how to set this in your platform in the tutorials included with the TeeChart installation, at the *Docs* folder.

Comment: Narcis, Thanks for you input. I had found the setting you suggested earlier but had more success opening the chart editor and going to Series1:Grid 3D tab:Grid Size:Depth and set it on'5' for a nice long (deep) chart. The only downside it decreases the height of the Left X-axis somewhat. I haven't found a way to increase depth without sacrificing some height on Left axis (Y values).